# xml file comparison

Tags: c#, xml, file

I want to only compare the nodes of two xml files but not the value of the nodes using c#.
If the node format in two files are not same then it should pop-up a message..

Answer (score 0):

I will use Linq to XML :

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(data);

var list = doc.DescendantNodes().Where(i => i is XElement);

and then use this to compare :

foreach (var item in list)

{

if (((XElement)item).Name.LocalName == propert.Name)
 }

but your final implementation should check number of nodes and other issues

Answer (score 0):

```
        XDocument file1 = XDocument.Load("somefile1.xml");
        XDocument file2 = XDocument.Load("somefile2.xml");
        if (file1.Nodes().Intersect(file2.Nodes()).Count() > 0)
        MessageBox.Show("hey i popped up");
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: it is getting the whole element data but it does not compare the file with element name, it is comparing the whole element data..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "node format" you mean elements & their names, this will walk the element tree and compare the names:

```
void Main()
{
    XElement thing = new XElement("test",  new XElement("child") );
    XElement otherThing = new XElement("test",  new XElement("child") );

    var comparer = new XElementComparer();
    var areSame = comparer.Equals(thing, otherThing);

    Console.WriteLine(areSame);
}

class XElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
{
    public bool Equals(XElement first, XElement second)
    {
        if (first.Name != second.Name)
            return false;
        else if (!first.Elements().SequenceEqual(second.Elements(), this))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(XElement element) { return element.GetHashCode(); }
}
```